# how can i draw many animated shapes on swt Canvas?

Tags: java, swt

I am trying to draw many shapes on SWT canvas by iterating a list of shapes, paint them, set the new locations and redraw().
This is too slow.
what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From this high level perspective there's no flaw. If you need more information you should provide

- some distilled code (to detect programming flaws)
- the expected frame rate (to detect expectation flaws)
- the number of shapes (see above)

Answer (score -1):

Some quick research on the internet revealed that using a for loop might be a bit faster. It depends on how many shapes do you have?